# Tourism Multivariate Time Series Dataset (daily observations)

Tags: time-series

I am looking for a tourism related dataset (ideally air traffic) with daily observations and a reasonable number of dimensions (thinking at least 1000 observations, and over 50 dimensions), ideally it would include the year 2020 (i.e. it has the impact of COVID). Most tourism datasets aggregate monthly/annually, and if they do aggregate daily they are only one or two dimensions. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what I was looking for here [EU airport traffic dataset](https://ansperformance.eu/data/). Daily observations for many EU airports going back to January 1 2016.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [anyflights](https://github.com/simonpcouch/anyflights) R package. - The anyflights package supplies a set of functions to generate air travel data. (but not vacation inforamtion and traveller information) - similar to [nycflights13](https://github.com/hadley/nycflights13) with its 337000 + x  rows in ~45 columns

- Gather flights + airlines metadata from https://openflights.org/data.html
- or from https://www.transtats.bts.gov/databases.asp